# How can I limit in xsl-fo to print at maximum 3 rows for column?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

So sample code:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="topTableInfo">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Helvetica</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<fo:table>
    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="50mm"/>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="topTableInfo">
                <fo:block margin-bottom="0.2cm" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="x/y"/> - <xsl:value-of select="x/z"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table>
```

My issue is here:

```
<xsl:value-of select="x/y"/> - <xsl:value-of select="x/z"/>
```

I want this text to occupy **maximum of 3 rows of text** in this block. The text maybe 1 row or 2 row but should not exceed 3 rows. How can I do this?

x/y is generated dynamically by some input from the user.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example of `x/y` or `x/z`? I can't figure out how it can generate more than one row in the table.

Comment: @potame They are just some strings.. Like "foo bar fooofofofo bar bar bar" Why do you say it can't generate more than 1 row of text in a block?

Comment: @potame I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit clearer, but what would like to do with overflowed text? Should it be discarded?

Comment: Use a block-container with a fixed height and set overflow to clip out the content. You will need to set the height based on the font-size to get only the lines you need.

Comment: @potane yes, just discarded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the new comment below, the only way I can think of that works with all formatters would be to estimate the number of characters that would land you in the third line. You can be approximate, like I would choose an average amount of content and count the number of characters to place you in the middle of the third line.

Then, implement in your XSL an if to add those attributes like this:

```
  <xsl:if test="string-length($lengthofstring) > ##">
     <xsl:attribute name="height">40pt</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="overflow">hidden</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

So anything that is three lines or greater would have the height and overflow, anything less than that would not have any and would only be the height of the content.

It's not totally generic but would do the job for known widths and font sizes of content.

Comment: Thanks, but now if the text is only 1 row the block still will be 3 rows which I do not like.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already trying this in the velocity template that I use to generate the string. But unfortunately sometimes the text will fall too short, and sometimes it will overflow to 4th line. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is likely because of the use of long strings and your inability to control where breaks are. As shown in your example, the line breaks early with space on it. You can only clip it in FO or you have to perform a two step process and calculate the breaks and set the heights.